# Song lyric generator using Markov Chains - Python

Tags: python, natural-language-processing, music, markov-chain

I have written a pop song generator which uses the Markovify library to produce lyrics based on (just for testing purposes) songs by Avril Lavigne.

In order to make the generator a bit more competent I have adapted some code which uses the `nltk` library to determine whether or not two words rhyme. I have used this to make the verses conform to an ABAC rhyme scheme.

It works, but is slow and sometimes gets stuck in a loop when the `rhyme_finder` function is called. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions as to how to streamline the programme, and or make it more efficient. I have linked the main programme `app.py` below, as well as the `rhyme_finder` function. But the Avril Lavigne lyrics, and the `nltk.tokenize` lyrics are on Pastebin.

The `Markovify` lib (https://github.com/jsvine/markovify), the `Sylco` syllable counter (https://github.com/eaydin/sylco), and some `nltk` dependencies (`cmudict`) are required to run.

**Lyric Generator**

```
import random
import markovify
import ast
from rhyme import rhyme_finder
from sylco import sylco

# Open and model lyrics
with open('lavigne_verse.txt') as f:
    verse_text = f.read()
with open('lavigne_chorus.txt') as f:
    chorus_text = f.read()
with open('lyrics_tokenize.txt') as f:
    tokenized_text = f.read()

verse_model = markovify.NewlineText(verse_text, state_size=2)
chorus_model = markovify.NewlineText(chorus_text, state_size=2)

# Evaluate tokenized_text as a list
tokenized_text = ast.literal_eval(tokenized_text)

# Specify then remove punctuation
punc = set([',','.','"','?','!'])

def clean(str):
    if str[-1] in punc:
        return str[:-1]
    return str

# Generate line that rhymes with stem of verse line 1
def match_rhyme(stem, verse_model):

    # Check if rhymes exist
    try:
        ls = rhyme_finder(stem, tokenized_text)
    except KeyError:
        return None
    if not ls:
        return None

    # If rhymes exist generate lines
    for n in range(100):
        while True:
            rhyme_line = verse_model.make_sentence()

            if rhyme_line is not None:

                # Keep syllables within range
                syl_count = sylco(rhyme_line)
                if syl_count > 16 or syl_count < 6:
                    continue

                # Get stem of rhyme_line
                rhyme_stem = clean(rhyme_line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1])

                # Check for rhyme
                if rhyme_stem in ls:
                    return rhyme_line

                break


    return None

# Generate 4-line verse
def make_verse(verse_model):
    verse = ''
    stem = None

    # Markovify for each line
    for _ in range(4):
        while True:

            # Try to find rhyming match between lines 1 and 3
            if _ == 2:
                match = match_rhyme(stem, verse_model)

                # If match, add to verse.
                if match is not None:
                    verse += (match + '\n')
                    break

            # Otherwise add non-random markovify line
            line = verse_model.make_sentence()

            if line is not None:

                # Keep syllables within range
                syl_count = sylco(line)
                if syl_count > 16 or syl_count < 6:
                    continue

                # Cache line for rhyming
                if _ == 0:
                    stem = clean(line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1])

                verse += (line + '\n')
                break

    return verse

# Construct chorus
def make_chorus(chorus_model):
    chorus = '[Chorus]' + '\n'

    # Two short lines
    for _ in range(2):
        while True:

            line = chorus_model.make_sentence()
            if line is not None:

                # Keep syllables less than 11
                syl_count = sylco(line)
                if syl_count > 10:
                    continue

                chorus += (line + '\n')
                break

    # Two line reprieve
    while True:
        repeat = chorus_model.make_sentence()

        if repeat is not None:
            chorus += (repeat + '\n')
            chorus += (repeat + '\n')
            break

    return chorus

# Construct song
def make_song(chorus_model, verse_model):

    song_chorus = make_chorus(chorus_model)

    song = make_verse(verse_model) + '\n' + song_chorus + '\n' \
            + make_verse(verse_model) + '\n' + make_verse(verse_model) + '\n'\
            + (2 * (song_chorus + '\n'))

    return song

print (make_song(chorus_model, verse_model))
```

**Rhyme_finder**

```
import random
import re
import operator
from nltk.corpus import cmudict

e = cmudict.entries()
d = cmudict.dict()

def make_word_list(tokenized_text):
    word_list = []
    for i in tokenized_text:
        try:
            d[i.lower()]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            if i.lower() == "'s":
                pass
            elif i[-1] == ".":
                pass
            else:
                word_list.append((i.lower(), d[i.lower()][0]))
    return word_list

def unique(s):
    u = []
    for x in s:
        if x not in u:
            u.append(x)
        else:
            pass
    return u

def meter(word):
    pron = d[word]
    m1 = []
    m2 = []
    mx = []
    if len(pron) == 1:
        for i in pron[0]:
            if '0' in i:
                m1.append(0)
            elif '1' in i:
                m1.append(1)
            elif '2' in i:
                m1.append(2)
            else:
                pass
         mx = [m1]
    elif len(pron) >= 2:
        for i in pron[0]:
            if '0' in i:
                m1.append(0)
            elif '1' in i:
                m1.append(1)
            elif '2' in i:
                m1.append(2)
            else:
                pass
        for i in pron[1]:
            if '0' in i:
                m2.append(0)
            elif '1' in i:
                m2.append(1)
            elif '2' in i:
                m2.append(2)
            else:
                pass
        mx = [m1, m2]
    m = []
    if len(mx) == 1:
        w0 = reduce(operator.mul, mx[0], 1)
        if w0 >= 2:
            for i in mx[0]:
                if i == 1:
                    m.append('u')
                elif i == 2:
                    m.append('s')
        elif w0 == 1:
            for i in mx[0]:
                m.append('s')
        elif w0 == 0:
            for i in mx[0]:
                if i == 0:
                    m.append('u')
                elif i == 1 or i == 2:
                    m.append('s')
    elif len(mx) == 2:
        w0 = reduce(operator.mul, mx[0], 1)
        w1 = reduce(operator.mul, mx[1], 1)
        if w0 >= 2 and w1 >= 2:
            for (i, j) in zip(mx[0], mx[1]):
                if i * j == 1:
                    m.append('u')
                elif i * j == 4:
                    m.append('s')
                elif i * j == 2:
                    m.append('x')
        elif w0 == 1 and w1 == 1:
            for (i, j) in zip(mx[0], mx[1]):
                m.append('s')
       elif w0 == 0 and w1 == 0:
            for (i, j) in zip(mx[0], mx[1]):
                if i == j and i * j >= 1:
                    m.append('s')
                elif i != j and i * j == 0:
                    m.append('x')
                elif i == j and i * j == 0:
                    m.append('u')
        elif w0 >= 2 and w1 == 0:
            for (i, j) in zip(mx[0], mx[1]):
                if i == 1 and j == 0:
                    m.append('u')
                elif i == 2 and j == 0:
                    m.append('x')
                elif i == 1 and j == 1:
                    m.append('x')
                elif i == 1 and j == 2:
                    m.append('x')
                elif i == 2 and j == 1:
                    m.append('s')
                elif i == 2 and j == 2:
                    m.append('s')
        elif w0 == 0 and w1 >= 2:
            for (i, j) in zip(mx[0], mx[1]):
                if i == 0 and j == 1:
                    m.append('u')
                elif i == 0 and j == 2:
                    m.append('x')
                elif i == 1 and j == 1:
                    m.append('x')
                elif i == 2 and j == 1:
                    m.append('x')
                elif i == 1 and j == 2:
                    m.append('s')
                elif i == 2 and j == 2:
                    m.append('s')
        elif w0 == 1 and w1 >= 2:
            for (i, j) in zip(mx[0], mx[1]):
                if j == 1:
                    m.append('x')
                elif j == 2:
                    m.append('s')
        elif w0 >= 2 and w1 == 1:
            for (i, j) in zip(mx[0], mx[1]):
                if i == 1:
                    m.append('x')
                elif i == 2:
                    m.append('s')
        elif w0 == 1 and w1 == 0:
            for (i, j) in zip(mx[0], mx[1]):
                if j == 0:
                    m.append('x')
                elif j == 1:
                    m.append('s')
                elif j == 2:
                    m.append('s')
        elif w0 == 0 and w1 == 1:
            for (i, j) in zip(mx[0], mx[1]):
                if i == 0:
                    m.append('x')
                if i == 1:
                    m.append('s')
                if i == 2:
                    m.append('s')
    return m

def strip_numbers(x):
    xj = '.'.join(x)
    xl = re.split('0|1|2', xj)
    xjx = ''.join(xl)
    xlx = xjx.split('.')
    return xlx

def last_stressed_vowel(word):
    if len(d[word]) <= 1:
        pron = d[word][0]
    else:
        p0 = d[word][0]
        p1 = d[word][1]
        sj0 = ''.join(p0)
        sl0 = re.split('0|1|2', sj0)
        sj1 = ''.join(p1)
        sl1 = re.split('0|1|2', sj1)
        if len(sl1) < len(sl0):
            pron = p1
        else:
            pron = p0
    mtr = meter(word)
    vowel_index = []
    if len(mtr) == 1:
        lsv = -1
    elif mtr[-1] == 's' or mtr[-1] == 'x':
        lsv = -1
    elif mtr[-2] == 's' or mtr[-3] == 'x':
        lsv = -2
    elif mtr[-3] == 's' or mtr[-3] == 'x':
        lsv = -3
    elif mtr[-4] == 's' or mtr[-4] == 'x':
        lsv = -4
    elif mtr[-5] == 's' or mtr[-5] == 'x':
        lsv = -5
    elif mtr[-6] == 's' or mtr[-6] == 'x':
        lsv = -6
    elif mtr[-7] == 's' or mtr[-7] == 'x':
        lsv = -7
    elif mtr[-8] == 's' or mtr[-8] == 'x':
        lsv = -8
    elif mtr[-9] == 's' or mtr[-9] == 'x':
        lsv = -9
    elif mtr[-10] == 's' or mtr[-10] == 'x':
        lsv = -10
    else:
        lsv = -1
    for i in pron:
        if '0' in i or '1' in i or '2' in i:
            vowel_index.append(pron.index(i))
        else:
            continue
    return vowel_index[lsv]

def rhyme_finder(word, tokenized_text):
    word_list = make_word_list(tokenized_text)
    word_list_u = unique(word_list)
    rhyming_words = []
    if len(d[word]) <= 1:
        pron = d[word][0]
    else:
        p0 = d[word][0]
        p1 = d[word][1]
        sj0 = ''.join(p0)
        sl0 = re.split('0|1|2', sj0)
        sj1 = ''.join(p1)
        sl1 = re.split('0|1|2', sj1)
        if len(sl1) < len(sl0):
            pron = p1
        else:
            pron = p0
    pron = strip_numbers(pron)
    lsv = last_stressed_vowel(word)
    rhyme_part = pron[lsv:]
    lrp = len(rhyme_part) * -1
    for (x, y) in word_list_u:
        ps = strip_numbers(y)
        if ps[lrp:] == rhyme_part and ps[lrp-1:] != pron[lsv-1:]:
            rhyming_words.append(x)
        else:
            pass
    rw = [i for i in rhyming_words if not i == word]
    return rw
```

`lavigne_verse.txt` = http://pastebin.com/HkXzr1eB

`lavigne_chorus.txt` = http://pastebin.com/apD7QxHC

`lavigne_tokenize.txt` = http://pastebin.com/khzjndPT

Many thanks!

Comment: Instead of "if line is not None:" you could simply go for "if line:". Further, you could some more functions for all the if elifs such as in meter(word) function. This would improve readability.

Comment: Yes you're right. Also just realised that the syllable counter in the `rhyme_finder` function does not do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

```
def unique(s):
    u = []
    for x in s:
        if x not in u:
            u.append(x)
        else:
            pass
    return u
```

may become much simpler:

```
def unique(s):
    return list(set(s))
```

but - as you use it only in one place

```
word_list_u = unique(word_list)
```

and in turn the `word_list_u` is used only in one place, too:

```
for (x, y) in word_list_u:
```

where `word_list_u` need not be a list.

So you may delete both the `unique()` definition and its usage, and write directly

```
for (x, y) in set(word_list):
```

as sets in Python inherently not allow duplicates.

---

```
punc = set([',','.','"','?','!'])

def clean(str):
    if str[-1] in punc:
        return str[:-1]
    return str
```

would be clearer with using the `endswith()` method and a *tuple* of punctuation symbols:

```
punc = tuple(',."?!')

def clean(str):
    if str.endswith(punc):
        return str[:-1]
    return str
```

Answer (score 2):

In this part of your code

```
elif mtr[-1] == 's' or mtr[-1] == 'x':
    lsv = -1
elif mtr[-2] == 's' or mtr[-3] == 'x':
    lsv = -2
elif mtr[-3] == 's' or mtr[-3] == 'x':
    lsv = -3
elif mtr[-4] == 's' or mtr[-4] == 'x':
    lsv = -4
elif mtr[-5] == 's' or mtr[-5] == 'x':
    lsv = -5
elif mtr[-6] == 's' or mtr[-6] == 'x':
    lsv = -6
elif mtr[-7] == 's' or mtr[-7] == 'x':
    lsv = -7
elif mtr[-8] == 's' or mtr[-8] == 'x':
    lsv = -8
elif mtr[-9] == 's' or mtr[-9] == 'x':
    lsv = -9
elif mtr[-10] == 's' or mtr[-10] == 'x':
    lsv = -10
else:
    lsv = -1
```

you probably have an error:

```
elif mtr[-2] == 's' or mtr[-3] == 'x':       # both indices have to be -2
```

and you can shorten it, too:

```
for i in range(-1, -11, -1):
    if mtr[i] in 'sx':
        lsv = i
        break
else:
    lsv = -1
```

(The `else` clause in a `for` loop is performed if and only if the loop finishes without encountering `break`.)